# What is the legal ramifications of refusing a polygraph?

Tags: united-states, employment, civil-rights

If an employer puts it in the work contract that they may require a polygraph (either to gain employment or keep it) can I refuse?

The relevant statutory body regarding polygraphs in the US mentions on their website that nobody can be forced to do a polygraph. It also mentions refusing to do one is not an admission of guilt.

Comment: Please provide a link to the website of the "relevant statutory body "

Comment: Of course you can refuse. And, if you have certain security clearances, those will be terminated. Which may also terminate your employment if your job requires them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends. There is a law, [29 USC Ch. 22](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/chapter-22), which generally prohibits employers from requiring polygraph tests before or during employment. However, there are exceptions. It only limits private employers, not governments; certain private employers are allowed to require such tests. The exemptions are set out [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/2006). They broadly fall into "government security concerns" (defense subcontractors etc.), security firms, and drug companies.

The penalties to be visited on violators are spelled out [here](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/polygraph).